# Android camera app for "non-linear" picture component piecing together

Tags: android, camera, mapping

The stock camera app on my Samsung Galaxy SIII has a "panoramic" mode whereby I can drag the camera around my body acting as a pivot to capture a panoramic view going from anywhere from x to 360°.

However, such panoramic view is only linear. I would like to be able to capture a grid of photos, which would be assembled together.

I was wondering if this were possible by moving the camera around as follows:

[image: rectangular grid panoramic view]

I would also like, in a similar fashion, to be able to capture a sky or dome, by doing a normal 360° panoramic view, and then shifting the camera upwards (one square), then repeating the 360° turn, and so on, till the camera is vertical:

[image: hemisphherical grid panoramic view]

The individual pieces are then pieced together, as normal.

Answer (score 1):

While not an Android application you can do this **offline** with [Hugin](http://hugin.sourceforge.net/), *note that there have been at least some attempts to port Hugin to Android*:

- Cross Platform *Windows, OS-X, Linux*
- Free, Gratis & Open Source
- Internationalised - *Brazilian Portuguese, Bulgarian, Catalan, Chinese Simplified, Chinese Traditional, Czech, Dutch, Danish, English, French, German, Hungarian, Italian, Japanese, Korean, Polish, Russian, Slovakian, Slovenian, Spanish, Swedish and Ukrainian translations*
- Simple Linear Stitching **Yes**
- Grid Stitching **Yes**
- Out of order stitching **Yes**
- Produce very high resolution image **Yes**
- Straighten skewed shots **Yes**
- Simulating an architectural projection including correcting Barrel & Perspective distortions **Yes**
- Combine pictures taken with different lenses or cameras **Yes**
- Focal Stacking **Yes**
- Exposure Correction **Yes** - the different shots taken on autoexposure are likely to be exposed differently Hugin can correct for this
- "[Little Planet](https://ultrawide.wordpress.com/2008/11/20/how-to-create-a-little-planet-using-hugin/)" **Yes**

[image]

*Note that I have not used any of the Android Apps that try to do this but have had very good results from running Hugin on various platforms*